# Connect to Oracle using Slick

Tags: oracle, scala, slick

I am trying to connect to Oracle using Slick.

I got the `slick-extensions_2.10-1.0.0.jar`.

Added the line below in Scala

```
Database.forURL("jdbc:oracle:thin:@myhost:myport:dbalias", "myid", "mypwd", null, driver = 
"com.typesafe.slick.driver.oracle.OracleDriver") withSession {.......}
```

What is the right URL to use for this driver since I got the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@myhost:myport:dbalias
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at scala.slick.session.Database$$anon$2.createConnection(Database.scala:105)
    at scala.slick.session.BaseSession.conn$lzycompute(Session.scala:207)
    at scala.slick.session.BaseSession.conn(Session.scala:207)
    at scala.slick.session.BaseSession.close(Session.scala:221)
    at scala.slick.session.Database.withSession(Database.scala:38)
    at scala.slick.session.Database.withSession(Database.scala:46)
```

Comment: Note that there is a high cost if you use Slick with Oracle in production. See the slick-extensions license.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you did not make the oracle jdbc driver available in classpath when running your program.

Comment: I think it's complaining about Oracle thin driver not in classpath, which is indeed not there.

Comment: But I think it's looking for the thin driver because the db URL I specified is copied from a typical java program that uses the thin driver. My question is what is the proper db URL for using the Oracle driver in slick-extensions jar.

Comment: Unfortunately, slick-extension is a closed source package, and nothing useful found in the [Doc](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/1.0.1/extensions.html) . I think slick-extension is just a wrapper for oracle jdbc driver, you still need the thin driver, so why not try to add the jar to dependencies and see if the problem remains?